# OCMock Partial mock only for descendant class

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I'm trying to set some unit test in our huge project. The problem is that some ViewControllers when called partial mock crash with following trace:

```
error: -[EspionageViewControllerTests testFillEspionageTabInfo] : failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "EspionageViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set."
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111264f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110efdbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111264e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
        3   UIKit                               0x000000010f68805f -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 441
        4   UIKit                               0x000000010f688588 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
        5   UIKit                               0x000000010f6887f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
        6   UIKit                               0x000000010f688c8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
        7   AppName                   0x000000010c07c388 -[IOViewController setTopBarView:] + 1144
```

As I understand I had problems with setTopBarView, and especially a place where I made following:

```
[viewElement setFrame:CGRectMake(viewElement.frame.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y - viewElement.frame.size.height , viewElement.frame.size.width, viewElement.frame.size.height)];
```

So the self.view call makes this crash. My question is how can I avoid this situation - especially when my EspionageViewController is subclass of another ViewController where setTopBarView is defined. I need to use OCMPartialMock on EspionageVC as otherwise I won't be able to check it's methods, however it's super class(and methods) must be fully mocked to prevent those crashes. Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are asking. Partial mock objects do allow you to mock methods in parent classes. It might be helpful if you shared a small example of the test code that causes the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response to my own question. The problem turns out to be pretty simple. I was mocking ViewController the following way:

```
id mock = OCMPartialMock([MyViewController new]);
```

Which of course is wrong and crash log was correct that my view outlets were not set(because I did not really load my xib file). So all i had to do was to create VC with designated initializier(hence to load it's xib):

```
id mock = OCMPartialMock([[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromSelector([MyViewController class]) bundle:nil]);
```